# Error using application.filedialog to open a file VBA7.0

Tags: excel, vba, visio, openfiledialog

I have recently installed visio 2010. it has VBA 7.0.

I am trying to write a code to open a file dialog, choose an excel file and open it. 
I used this code

```
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

but i get the following error:

> Run-time error '438':
>   Object doesn't support this property or method

i already have the `Microsoft Office 14. Object Library` as reference.

Do you have an idea? what i should do?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this code in Visio

```
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

the word `Application` refers to Visio and as you can see in Object Browser, `Visio.Application` class has no such method as `FileDialog`. Access and Excel applications have it, but not Visio.

In order to use it in Visio you need to add reference to either ***Microsoft Excel Object Library*** or ***Microsoft Access Object Library***. Then you need to use the code below to create an instance of `FileDialog` (select a proper version depending on what reference did you add to your project - Excel or Access)

```
'If you have reference to Microsoft Excel Object Library
Set fd = Excel.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

or

```
'If you have reference to Microsoft Access Object Library
Set fd = Access.Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like explained by @mielk, Visio does not have the `Application.FileDialog`. You could use the method of Excel (in this case you'll have to have Excel installed, and started to invoke its methods) or use pure WinAPI from VBA (i.e. `GetOpenFileName` function). This option is explained here for example:

http://visguy.com/vgforum/index.php?topic=738.0